# Expectations of functions of random variables

Tags: probability

If $f$ is an $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ function and $X$ is a random variable, $f(X)$ is also a random variable. How does one define $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]?$ I would say:

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\sum f(x_i)\mathbb{P}\Big(f(X)=f(x_i)\Big)\quad (a)$$

Is this correct? From reading things I get the impression that:

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\sum f(x_i)\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)\quad (b)$$

Isn't $(b)$ only equivalent if $f$ is injective?

Comment: Following the logic, your (a) should be $E(f(X))=\sum\limits_yyP(f(X)=y)$, then (a) is indeed equivalent to (b). This is sometimes called the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If rv $X$ only takes values in countable set $\left\{ x_{i}\mid i\in I\right\} $ where the $x_{i}$ are distinct then (b) is correct with summation over set $I$. If
$f$ is not injective then the $f\left(x_{i}\right)$ are not distinct,
so by summation over $I$ some values are counted more than once.